# Conflict between jQuery and another js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I added this following script to my html without any problem:

```
<link href="multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="multiselect.min.js"></script>
```

...

```
<script>
    document.multiselect('#selection');     
</script>
```

However, as soon as I include this following jQuery, it is said that `document.multiselect is not a function`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="multiselect.min.js"></script>
```

Why there would be such a conflict? How should I resolve?

Comment: can you add your full html page code?

Comment: do you have more than on version of jQuery?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't make sense.  The jQuery library is only going to create the `window.jQuery` and `window.$` namespaces.  It's not going to remove other logic from other places.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pvm5gwc6/  Can't replicate it.

Comment: What's the source of 'multiselect.min.js' - looks like it's conflicting with jquery

Answer (score 2):

Add the jQuery line at the very end of your header, which will solve the issue:

```
<link href="multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="multiselect.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```